# Will Google recognize a comma as a separator in page titles without spaces?

Tags: seo, title, delimiter

I know that it is allowed in SEO to use comma as separator but, is it ok to add comma as a separator between keywords in `title` without leaving a space?

Example:

```html
<title>High blood pressure,Hypertension</title>
```

Comment: Yes you can... but why would you want too? It's ugly and harder to read for your visitors. Google title length limit is no longer done by characters, its by pixels and changes per a device... but anyhow... Pretty titles are for visitors, not search bots.

Comment: Thanks, Actually, they are already like this after technical error, so I was wondering if I should change them

Comment: SEO won't improve but click rates should improve.

Comment: Both GOV UK and NHS use `High blood pressure (hypertension)`, Bupa UK uses `High blood pressure | Healthcare | Bupa UK`. Google is smart enough to link words, so even if the user forgets to type hypertension Google will fill in the blanks, assuming its in the meta description. `,` is a good word separator assuming its has a space after it, giving you some distance between words, without it is weak... this applies to all symbols that help separate word e.g `Good Health (Guide)` `Bad Health(Guide)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use any sign as separator, but you should always keep the readability in view. Suffering readability will for sure suffer your SERP CTR - and this would be too bad, to get an impression but to loose the click.

Google will recognize your keywords anyway - it will do it based on words placed befor and after  words, which are weirdly separated, like in your example. Compare SERPs on these three searches:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=high+blood+pressure,+hypertension
- https://www.google.com/search?q=high+blood+pressurehypertension
- https://www.google.com/search?q=high+blood+pressure,hypertension

They are the same - ergo Google recognizes them all. But seeing such in the page title would not necessarily motivate to clik it.

Answer (score 1):

In Google, you use three things to separate data in the search engine.

1. Comma(,)
2. Hypen(-)
3. Pipe (|)

Comment: Can you cite any kind of source for this?